# Are these cracks in this pergola of Nordic Pine wood something to be concerned about for use as a base for synthetic ceramic roof tiles?

Tags: wood-movement, moisture, construction

I had a pergola installed a month or two ago. The material was Nordic Pine, and it was treated with a layer of isolating finish. I noticed that there are many cracks already in the wood:

[image]
[image]

There are many more but these are the worst-looking ones.

At least some of these were already present before the finish was applied.

The person who built the pergola assured me it's not a problem and that it's normal and water won't get in because it is well-isolated. I'm a total novice, but visually it seems like the inside of the wood is exposed to the open air and that water and humidity would clearly get in.

I plan to have an awning installed on top of it, using synthetic ceramic tiles (so, not as heavy as real ceramic). So once the roof is installed it at least won't rain directly on the wood. But moisture might still be an issue. However I asked the opinion of the awning person and he said it shouldn't be any issue for him, just that the awning will make it harder for us to maintain the wood.

My questions are:

- Are the cracks something to be concerned about for structural soundness?
- Should I do anything (e.g. crack off the breaking parts and apply a few more layers of finish) before having the awning installed?

Comment: Honestly doesn't look like a problem to me, even less of one if you are putting an awning over.  large beams crack and split all the time,   It's not a problem.  And even the 'finish' you have on them are not %100 waterproof, moisture goes in and out of wood as the seasons change, finishes just slow it down a lot.

Answer (score 4):

> Are the cracks something to be concerned about for structural soundness?

I want to reassure, and as @bowlturner says in a Comment, large beams do crack/split all the time. Even major structural elements in full-size buildings can have cracks plural in them — occasionally one or more being wide, deep and long — and remain sound. This is in part because most structures are overbuilt, with the overall structure and most or all individual components being stronger than they need to be.

[image: Cracks in structural timbers]

But, I do want to caution that it is difficult to *try* to interpret the cracks in your pergola without seeing the whole thing from multiple angles. And this sort of thing is anyway partly a judgement call, based on a hunches (read: guesswork) rather than sure knowledge of what will happen in the future.

And furthermore I would have some worries myself TBH, and would scrutinise the structure for other telling signs of, well, *anything* more to be concerned about. Particularly any more sign of inferior material, which MIGHT be the underlying cause of the splits shown.

OK, now the reassuring stuff.

I can't be certain, and the second image isn't large enough to really have a close look, but I think both photos show these members are *laminations*. Laminations are in general much stronger and more stable than solid wood of the same dimensions, so the simple fact of their use is a positive sign. One way that they're superior is that cracks starting at one of the outer edges can't propagate through the width/thickness in the way they can sometimes in single pieces of wood — a crack would have to cross a glue line (should be very, very strong) and then continue into wood with a completely different flow of grain.

---

> I'm a total novice, but visually it seems like the inside of the wood is exposed to the open air and that water and humidity would clearly get in.

Humidity isn't really of any concern. Direct rainwater exposure is, but once the roof is on at least some of the wood will have some protection from the weather<sup>1</sup>.

You will have to maintain the finish on the woodwork to protect it from the elements, with possibly annual or biannual touch-ups and the occasional complete once-over on all exposed surfaces (perhaps every 5-7 years).

> Should I do anything (e.g. crack off the breaking parts and apply a few more layers of finish) before having the awning installed?

Where possible (where access allows) I would personally want to glue down errant pieces, if they can be flexed back into position<sup>2</sup> without just snapping off, and IF the surfaces exposed are bare wood.

Where a crack exposes wood that already has finish on it you can't be sure it will glue strongly or at all. I'd probably just leave any such cracks for now as long as there wasn't a hazardous 'splinter' sticking out!

---

<sup>1</sup> Should be obvious but in case not, lower down the wood will have lots more exposure than the wood higher up. The pieces directly under the roof especially will be substantially protected from precipitation and sunlight. Focus attention on the stuff that'll see the most weather.

<sup>2</sup> Note that doing this cleanly and neatly will require care and attention, and while you can do a lot with masking tape and/or wraps of string or cord you might need some clamps. You'll want to bring yourself up to speed on how to apply glue into cracks as well as how to thoroughly clean up squeeze-out and drips afterwards.

Comment: Awesome post Ty! From what you describe I think it is laminations, see more photos here: https://imgur.com/a/eD4q3Yz . Noted about gluing the errant wood down, I will investigate

Comment: Welcome. Oh yes, much clearer photos showing lamination as there are knots interrupted by the original edges of the boards throughout. For what it's worth, looking at more of the overall structure I am more reassured this was done well.